# Insert date into SQL without taking care of the regional settings

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

my question looks simple: in my client/server application I want to record a specific date provided by the client.
The problem is that I don't know the regional settings of the  client, and I don't know the regional settings of the SQL Server.

How can the client application provide a date in whatever format (last login of a specific user) and store it in a SQL Server table that might be installed with a different regional settings (french, english, italian, german, etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: don't use strings. Use a parameter that is typed as a datetime; can be as simple as:

```
DateTime when = ...

using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "... @when ...";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("when", when);
    cmd.ExecuteNotQuery();
}
```

or with "dapper":

```
conn.Execute("... @when ...", new { when });
```

Dates/times are actually just numbers. It is only when you write/parse it as a string that formatting is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just store everything in UTC date in sqlserver. And while retrieving the date convert the utc date to the timezone of the user. I hope users timezone is maintained in your database.
You will need a timezone table and a conversion function that will convert the UTC time to the users local time.

Comment: The UTC issue is a very valid one and worthy of mention; my interpretation is that the question is talking about the *formatting* issue, but this is important too. Note that even internationally, both UTC and local dates can be the most appropriate representation, depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

to insert a date in SQL use a string in the form 'YYYYMMDD'
what comes from the client-side you sould know what is it

Comment: It is much better to not use any format at all, but to use a typed parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should use Parameters, but you also can format date to ISO format by `date.ToString("s")`

Answer (score 0):

Use datetime format, and **store dates as UTC time**.

You'll probably also be interested in [datetimeoffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Validation part**

```
DateTime dt;
string YourDate = "Your Date";
if (DateTime.TryParse(YourDate, out dt))
{
     //Your Code
}
```

---

**Stored Procedure Record Insertion/Retrieval**

```
using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnection string")) 
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string expression = "Date Parameter value";
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(expression, out dt))
    {
       //Your Code
    }
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Your Stored Procedure";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Your Parameter Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = expression;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    using (IDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
    {
       if (dr.Read()) 
       {
       }
    }
}
```

While storing the data in Sql Server Keep the data format consistent and synchronized with the data format while retrieving....